# ¿Cómo filtrar información de Mysql con base al día de hoy?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una página que involucra filtrar información pero con base en fecha de hoy y un tipo de servicio en concreto.

```
SELECT id_servicio, fecha_servicio, tipo_servicio, nombre_servicio 
FROM servicios_totales 
WHERE tipo_servicio='Compra' AND fecha_servicio='09-03-2021' 
ORDER BY fecha_servicio ASC;
```

Ahora, quisiera saber cómo se agregaría la sentencia para que sólo salga la información de un tipo de servicio pero siempre con la fecha de hoy, de manera que no haya que estar cambiando manualmente la fecha, tal como pasaría si añado la sentencia anterior, que no cambia porque siempre es una condición estática. No sé si me explico. Lo anterior es para poder aplicarlo a mi página web, donde extraería la información de la BD usando `PHP`.

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas. Soy muy nuevo en esto del `MySQL` y aun estoy aprendiendo sobre el sistema. Espero me puedan comprender. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `date()` de `php` te puede ayudar con lo que buscas, ya que te permite obtener la fecha actual en el formato que le especifiques.

En el ejemplo te devuelve '2021-03-09', en tu caso puedes cambiar el orden de los parámetros a `date('d-m-Y')`.

Es importante que conserves las mayúsculas y minúsculas de los parámetros, ya que si los modificas, te devuelve la fecha en un formato diferente.

Puedes asignar la fecha actual a una variable o directamente en la cláusula `where` de tu consulta.

```
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
SELECT id_servicio, fecha_servicio, tipo_servicio, nombre_servicio 
FROM servicios_totales 
WHERE tipo_servicio='Compra' AND fecha_servicio = $hoy
ORDER BY fecha_servicio ASC;
```

Más información sobre la función, aquí: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Cualquier duda, déjala en los comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL cuenta con la función `CURDATE()`, la cual, [según el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

> Returns the current date as a value in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `YYYYMMDD`
> format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric
> context.
>
> ---
>
> Devuelve la fecha actual como un valor en formato `'YYYY-MM-DD'` o
> `YYYYMMDD`, dependiendo de si la función se utiliza en un contexto de
> cadena o numérico.

Entonces, tu consulta puede ser escrita así, sin tener que depender del lenguaje:

```
SELECT id_servicio, fecha_servicio, tipo_servicio, nombre_servicio 
FROM servicios_totales 
WHERE tipo_servicio='Compra' AND fecha_servicio=CURDATE() 
ORDER BY fecha_servicio ASC;
```

### PD

Se da por supuesto que `fecha_servicio` es de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`. Si fuera de tipo `DATETIME` entonces habría que convertirla a `DATE` para que funcione: **`WHERE  DATE(fecha_servicio) = CURDATE()`**